# how to assign a control property value from a global variable in page code?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-controls

Greetings,

I have a control and list of variables and I want in the control property to be assigned to the variable value directly in the page not from the back code, something like this

My global variables

```
public string Banana = "banana_pie";
public string Apple = "apple_pie";
```

in my custom control instead of:

```
<uc:LoadPie id="pieBanana" type="banana_pie" />
```

To this

```
<uc:LoadPie id="pieBanana" type="<%=Banana %>" />
```

so is there a way or just assign the property in page back code.

Thanks

Comment: You title is clear, but the question itself isn't. How is what you have written related to the title? What exactly is your question? Why are resource files mentioned? Do you need to internationalize?

Comment: @Oded: I put the global variable as const in this example and I mentioned resource file as one of workarounds to solve this problem (wrong way to solve but it does solves it). what is the part of question is vague so I can update it. thx

Comment: @Oded: I updated my question if this makes it more clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this using data binding syntax.

```
<uc:LoadPie id="pieBanana" type='<%#Banana%>' runat="server"></uc:LoadPie>
```

But then in your code behind you have to call

```
pieBanana.DataBind();
```

in the page load in order for the databinding expression to be evaulated.

But if you are going to do this then you might as well assign the property in the page load.

Comment: you are right.
That's the way to go. Just a little typing error:
type='<%# Banana %>'

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with a property (protected should be enought, but I'll say public in the following snippet) in your code behind:

```
Public Property myBanana() As String
   Get
      Return Pies.Banana;
   End Get
End Property
```

Then you can use it in your controls, for example:

```
<uc:LoadPie id="pieBanana" type="<%= myBanana%>" />
```

Comment: In your code it will not send the property value as a value, it will send "<%= myBanana%>" string as a value to the type

Answer (score 0):

Not quite what you want, but how about:

```
<% pieBanana["type"] = this.Banana %>
```